# bspwm does not switch focus to my second screen. It works when going there with the mouse

Tags: linux, window-managers

I am trying to have desktops 1-4 on my laptop screen and 5-8 on my second screen.

Super 1-4 works fine on my laptop. But when I press Super 5-8, the focus stays on desktop 4, not switching to my 2nd screen.
When I move my mouse pointer to the second screen I can open apps there, and then Super 1-4 switch between desktops 5-8.

Somehow the focus switch does not work to my other monitor.

bspwmrc:

```
#! /bin/bash

pgrep -x sxhkd >/dev/null || sxhkd &
... other startup commands

start_from=1
monitors_connected=$(bspc query -M | wc -l)
per_monitor=$(( 8 / monitors_connected ))
for monitor in $(bspc query -M); do
   bspc monitor $monitor -d $(seq $start_from $(( start_from + per_monitor - 1)))
   start_from=$(( start_from + per_monitor ))
done
```

(I found this here: [bspwm workspaces not working after activating other monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63104980/bspwm-workspaces-not-working-after-activating-other-monitor))

sxhkdrc:

```
super + {_,shift + }{1-8}
    bspc {desktop --focus,node --to-desktop} 'focused:^{1-8}'
```

When I open a terminal on my second screen and type the command `bspc desktop --focus 2`, then the focus switches nicely to desktop 2 on my laptop screen.

UPDATE:
I think I can narrow this issue down to:
Why do Super 5-8 not work? And why are Super 1-4 on my second monitor going to desktops 5-8?

Answer (score 2):

In the meantime I solved it. I'll leave the solution here for others having similar issues.

I removed the word 'focused' from the command. That was basically it.
I also split the line into two separated lines for more flexibility.

```
super + {1-8}
    bspc desktop --focus ^{1-8}

super + shift + {1-8}
    bspc node --to-desktop} ^{1-8} --focus
```